# Auto create a feed when a node is added

Tags: 8, nodes

I am looking for a way to automatically add a feed (of a specific feed type), whenever a node is added (for a specific content type) using the node fields to auto-create the feed.

I have searched this site and globally; the closest solution I could find is the one described in [Programmatically create and trigger feeds importer](https://knackforge.com/blog/sivananda-perumal/programmatically-create-and-trigger-feeds-importer), for Drupal 7, although I cannot see why a template should be needed.

I think I should be able to do this in a custom module, but I am a bit stuck.

Does anyone know how this could be done in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for you is [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.9.x). Below is a simplified code sample; as always, use dependency injection and other best practices in your production code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update().
 */
function mymodule_node_update(\Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() === 'my_content_type') {
    $feed = \Drupal\feeds\Entity\Feed::create([
      // Name the new Feed after the node; or anything you want!
      'title' => "{$node->label()} importer",

      // Assign the ID of the Feed Type to use for generating this Feed.
      'type' => $feed_type_id,

      // This will vary depending on the type of importer.
      'source' => 'https://www.example.com/data.csv',

      // Optionally, set uid to 1 to always belong to the Drupal superuser.
      'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
    ]);
    // Kick off the import after successfully saving the Feed. 
    if (in_array($feed->save(), [SAVED_NEW, SAVED_UPDATED], TRUE)) {
      $feed->import();
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to use hook entity insert, though, since I need node id to reference.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Would you be kind enough to mark this as the accepted answer?